# HttpServletRequest how to get the parameter of an array

Tags: java

I know that in PHP we can do something like this

```
$_POST['x']['y'] or $_GET['x']['y']
```

to get a parameter but how is this working in Java with HttpServletRequest.getParameter();

Thank you

Comment: [The API may be of great use in this case.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String))

Comment: So no way to do this in only one line of code like PHP you have to do a new Map with the String ?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of how PHP's `$_GET` works (anymore), but if you're messing with `HttpServletRequest.getParameter(String)`, then...the only way to mess with it would be prescribed in the API.

Comment: ok i should use getParameterValues() then ;)

Comment: try getParameterValues. much like getParameter, but will return an array of all the parameters which match your name. getParameter is limited to one record

Comment: ok thanks Sean i will play with that, too bad that there is no 'out of the box' stuff for this :) (i was looking for one line of code... :/ )